# Database solution for chat app

Tags: ios, swift

I am building a chat app with swift.You know I need to store all messages in a database.But I am so confused right now.Because I found the core data but I am not sure it is good for this case.

I need to store all messages like this:

```
id  -> Primary key
sender -> String
receiver -> String
message -> String
date -> Integer
```

Is core data good for this case ? If it is not then which solution is good for this case ?

Ps:If you have a question please ask me in the comments.

Comment: That is a little better then your previous question - but still far from perfect. Yes, CoreData is good for that purpose, or you could just use plain sqlite.

Comment: If this was your app,which solution do you use ?

Comment: CoreData is a local DB, if you want a remote DB use for example MySQL and php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Core data obviously makes a lot of sense, the other option being something like realm.io which you might want to look into.

Otherwise it might be possible to store and hold small conversations in iOS keystore by senderid, though you'd need your back end to hold the rest and you wouldn't be able to query the data effectively.

In short though- use core data or realm.

Best of luck.